# How to validate json with some conditions

Tags: json, postman, jsonschema

There is some json.

```
{
  "headerInfo": {
    "id": 50
  "characteristics": [
    {
      "id": "123456789",
      "type": "float",
      "multiValued": false,
      "numberDecimals": 6,
      "length": 10,
      "caseSensitive": false,
      "entryFieldMask": "_,___.______",
      "unitOfMeasure": "P1",
      "additionalValues": true
    },
    {
      "id": "15151511",
      "type": "float",
      "multiValued": false,
      "numberDecimals": 0,
      "possibleValues": [
        {
          "valueLow": "60",
          "intervalType": "1"
        },
        {
          "valueLow": "80",
          "intervalType": "1"
        }
      ],
      "length": 3,
      "caseSensitive": false,
      "entryFieldMask": "___",
      "unitOfMeasure": "P1",
      "additionalValues": false
    },
    {
      "id": "489481561",
      "type": "string",
      "multiValued": false,
      "possibleValues": [
        {
          "id": "A"
        }
        {
          "id": "§"
        }
      ],
      "length": 1,
      "caseSensitive": true,
      "entryFieldMask": "",
      "additionalValues": false,
      "reference": {
        "name": "ghnfgjghjghk",
        "writable": false
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "4616616161",
      "type": "date",
      "multiValued": false,
      "length": 10,
      "caseSensitive": false,
      "entryFieldMask": "DD.MM.YYYY",
      "additionalValues": true,
      "reference": {
        "name": "bfhwbvbjewbv",
        "writable": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How to generate a json schema using the following conditions:

- the "reference" and "possibleValues" properties are optional.
- if the "type" property is equal to the "float" value, then the "numberDecimals" property is required, otherwise it is not.

I tried to implement this using anyOf, but in this case everything inside anyOf was not validated correctly, although in the postman validation was successful.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `if, then` syntax with JSON Schema draft-07 or newer.

The jist is you define the entire schema, and then at the object schema where you want to define `required` properties, you add the `if, then` syntax to check if the value matches the condition, then assign the `then` constraint.

In your case, we check `if` the constant value of `type` is `float`, if true, `required:["numberDecimals"]`

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "headerInfo": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "number"
        }
      }
    },
    "characteristics": {
      "type": "array",
      "uniqueItems": true,
      "items": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "multiValued": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "numberDecimals": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "length": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "caseSensitive": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "entryFieldMask": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "unitOfMeasure": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "additionalValues": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "reference": {
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "writable": {
                "type": "boolean"
              }
            }
          },
          "possibleValues": {
            "type": "array",
            "uniqueItems": true,
            "items": {
              "oneOf": [
                 {
                   "properties": {
                      "id": {
                        "type": "string"
                      }
                   }
                 },
                 {
                   "properties": {
                      "valueLow": {
                         "type": "string"
                      },
                      "intervalType": {
                         "type": "string"
                      }
                   }
                 }
               ]
            }
          }
        },
        "if": {
          "properties": {
            "type": {
              "const": "float"
            }
          }
        },
        "then": {
          "required": [
            "numberDecimals"
          ]
        },
        "required": [
          "id",
          "type",
          "multiValued",
          "length",
          "caseSensitive",
          "entryFieldMask",
          "additionalValues"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy's answer helped a lot, but it needed to be refined a little more, namely, to add the "required" property to oneOf. Here's what the final result will look like:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "headerInfo": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "number"
                }
            }
        },
        "characteristics": {
            "type": "array",
            "uniqueItems": true,
            "items": {
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "type": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "multiValued": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "numberDecimals": {
                        "type": "number"
                    },
                    "length": {
                        "type": "number"
                    },
                    "caseSensitive": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "entryFieldMask": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "unitOfMeasure": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "additionalValues": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "reference": {
                        "properties": {
                            "name": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "writable": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "possibleValues": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "uniqueItems": true,
                        "items": {
                            "oneOf": [{
                                    "required": [
                                        "id"
                                    ],
                                    "properties": {
                                        "id": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "required": [
                                        "valueLow",
                                        "intervalType"
                                    ],
                                    "properties": {
                                        "valueLow": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "intervalType": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "if": {
                    "properties": {
                        "type": {
                            "const": "float"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "then": {
                    "required": [
                        "numberDecimals"
                    ]
                },
                "required": [
                    "id",
                    "type",
                    "multiValued",
                    "length",
                    "caseSensitive",
                    "entryFieldMask",
                    "additionalValues"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```