# JSON Schema with a nested property whose existence depends on a value of another property from a higher scope

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm trying to create a JSON schema for a message passing system.  I currently have the following schema set up:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "Message",
    "description": "Just your average message",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "header": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "messageType": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "minLength": 1,
                    "enum": [
                        "message1",
                        "message2"
                    ]
                },
                "sender": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "minLength": 1
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "messageType",
                "sender"
            ]
        },
        "body": {}
    },
    "required": [
        "header",
        "body"
    ]
}
```

This works great for the header portion, however I would like to extend this validation to have the body to have certain required fields based on the value of "header -> messageType".  If "messageType" is "message1", the "body" requires a "prop1" field.  If "messageType is "message2", the "body" requires a value for "prop2".  So for example...

```
{
    "header": {
        "sender": "John Doe",
        "type": "message1"
    },
    "body": {
        "prop1": "Hello"
    }
}
```

...would be a valid object, but...

```
{
    "header": {
        "sender": "John Doe",
        "type": "message1"
    },
    "body": {}
}
```

...would not.  I tried reading the documentation on how to do this with "allOf" with if-else conditionals, but nothing I found works for trying to reference a field that is outside the scope of the body.  If anyone has any insight on this I would greatly appreciate it.  Bonus points for using definitions, as I eventually plan on extending this out to pull in the "body" structures from different schema files.

EDIT: Added further information for what fields are required based on message types.

Comment: are you stuck on draft-04?  `If, then` conditionals only became a thing in draft-07 or later.  If you're stuck at draft-04, we can try to come up with something for you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate json with some conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77160509/how-to-validate-json-with-some-conditions)

Comment: @JeremyFiel I'm not stuck on draft-04, no.  Though based on your comment I did try updating to 07 and am still having the same problem.

Comment: @JeremyFiel and in the article you linked, it looks like the dependent field was at the same level of nesting as the one conditionally required.  What I'm struggling with is the fact that I need to have required properties within an object that are based on a value in a different object with a different level of nesting.  Can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if, then` syntax in Draft-07 or newer to acheive this behavior. The trick is to use the conditional syntax at the top most level and drill down into the schema within the conditional statement. Then you can target the intended schema where you need constraints.

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "Message",
    "description": "Just your average message",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "header": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "messageType": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "minLength": 1,
                    "enum": [
                        "message1",
                        "message2"
                    ]
                },
                "sender": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "minLength": 1
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "messageType",
                "sender"
            ]
        },
        "body": {
            "properties": {
                "prop1": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "prop2": {
                    "type": "number"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "header",
        "body"
    ],
    "allOf": [
        {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "header": {
                        "properties": {
                            "messageType": {
                                "const": "message1"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "then": {
                "properties": {
                    "body": {
                        "required": [
                            "prop1"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "header": {
                        "properties": {
                            "messageType": {
                                "const": "message2"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "then": {
                "properties": {
                    "body": {
                        "required": [
                            "prop2"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: additional constraints to only allow certain `body` properties based on the `messageType` can be adjusted within the `then` statement